# Is there a way to match two time series covering same period but with different days missing?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two time series for interest rates. Both are daily, but one includes only trading days while the other includes every calendar day. I would like to match these series in adjacent columns to easily calculate a spread for each day on which data for both are available.

Is there an easy way to delete the extra days in the longer time series, or add blank (or interpolated) cells for the missing days for the shorter one? (That is, either delete the weekend etc. cells in the longer series, or add blank weekend etc. cells in the shorter one.) It doesn't much matter which.

I know how to plot them together in a chart, but I'd like to have them together in the spreadsheet with each date in the same row across both columns, to make calculations easier.

Thanks! (I'm using Excel 2016 for Mac.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be achieved by putting

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$9,0),0),"")
```

in F2 and filling down.

[image]

Comment: Sir A's solution makes the most sense, but it sounds like you want two columns of dates, with blanks for the missing values. If so, fill this down from C2: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$6,0)),"",D2)`

Comment: Thanks to you both. Sir Adelaide's answer gave exactly what I want. But Bandersnatch's formula, generating a column of dates with blanks where the dates are not available for the first series, could also come in handy for other applications.